# How to use console.log() to debug a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug my Chrome extension using

```
console.log("message");
```

My extension works fine (for the most part), I'm clicking buttons that call function which perform something. Every function as a consloe.log() debug line.

If I open the chrome console (ctrl + shift + i) after chrome loads, it remains empty, no matter what I do. Chrome is set to developer mode.

Comment: @BeardFist please change your comment to an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Make sure that you are opening the correct dev console. You need to go to the `generated background page` for the background page console and `right click -> inspect popup` for the popup console. There was an answer to a similar question with a nice gif, I will link it if I can find it.

Comment: GIF link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw8d5.gif

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913799/google-chrome-firefox-do-not-see-extension-output-in-console?noredirect=1&lq=1